# Creating a fully ajax based website with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

What I'm planning is creating a website that is based fully ajax requests. But there are some questions in my mind,

1- Should I use a javascript routing engine, library ext.? Do I really need it? Because the website I'm working on is very large and will surely grow up.

2- I will just load every page content via ajax, but I won't use `JSON`, I'm planning to use `PartialViews` is that OK?

3-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $("a.ajax").click(function() {
           $(".placeholder").load(this.href);
           return false;
       });

   </script>
   <a class="ajax" href="/Home/Products/2">Products</a>
   <div class="placeholder"></div>
```

This is the simple code of my process, the problem is here history, when user wants get back, it will fail. How can I achieve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

> 1- Should I use a javascript routing engine, library ext.? Do I really
>   need it? Because the website I'm working on is very large and will
>   surely grow up.

If you have lots of logic on the client you might consider using some MVVM javascript framework. [`KnockoutJS`](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [`AngularJS`](http://angularjs.org/) are some popular choices.

> 2- I will just load every page content via ajax, but I won't use JSON,
>   I'm planning to use PartialViews is that OK?

You could use the [`HTML5 History API`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-first-look-at-the-history-api/) which would allow you to add entries to the browser history everytime you make an AJAX request.

Here's an example:

```
$("a.ajax").click(function() {
    var href = this.href;
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(".placeholder").load(href, function() {
        // Add an entry in the browser history
        history.pushState(null, title, href);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, nice point. But I handle `a.ajax` click handler and I'm loading content via click. So what will happen if user wants to get back. How will handle it and load history page content?

Comment: Simply subscribe to the [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate) event which will be triggered when the browser loads an entry from the history and then reconstruct the page using the necessary AJAX calls to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on angularjs.
AngularJs + asp.net web api will be the good approach

Answer (score 0):

answer q1 : it is better to use some mvvm frameworks like angular.js but also you can handle everything yourself , ofcourse if you want to handle such things you must code much more !
answer  q2: it is ok ,simply call an action method via ajax call and in action method render a partialview and in your success function update anywhere you want , I am using this method too :)